# jssor slide transition options

Tags: transition, jssor

Clicking an arrow transitions with the incoming image "pushing" the current image out of the viewing area.  All of the _SlideshowTransitions options used so far seem to "overlay" the current image.  Is there a _SlideshowTransitions option available that will "push" the current image out of the viewing area like clicking an arrow does?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the transition code,

```
{$Duration:1200,x:1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart},$Brother:{$Duration:1200,x:-1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart}}}
```

or the transition code with fade,

```
{$Duration:1200,x:1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2,$Brother:{$Duration:1200,x:-1,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InOutQuart,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and code examples.  Transitions are now working as desired.